# Creating a formulaic query with multiple columns and joined columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to produce a formula which pits our students' reward points against their negative behaviour flags.

Students are given LEAP points (in the `transactions` table) for their positive behaviour. They get more points depending on the category of their reward, i.e. `Model Citizen` gives the student 10 points.

On the other hand, students are given single Flags for negative behaviour. The category of the Flag is then weighted in a database table, i.e. the `Aggressive Defiance` category will have a high weighting of `4` whereas `Low Level Disruption` will only be *worth* `1`.

The difficulty therefore is trying to factor in the Flag categories' weightings. They're stored in the `categories` table under the `Weight` column.

---

**Here's the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e5756**

---

In my head, the pseudo-SQL code would look something like this...

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( stu.Surname, ", ", stu.Firstname ) AS `Student`,
    SUM(t.Points) AS `LEAP Points`,
    SUM(<<formula>>) AS `Flags`
    ( `LEAP Points` - `Flags` ) AS `Worked Out Points Thing`
FROM student stu
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.Recipient_ID = stu.id
LEFT JOIN flags f ON f.Student_ID = stu.id
LEFT JOIN categories c ON f.Category_ID = c.ID
GROUP BY stu.id
```

However, it's the `<<formula>>` that I have no idea how to implement in MySQL. It needs to be something like this:

```
SUM OF[ Each of Student's Flags * that Flag's Category Weighting ]
```

So, if a student has these flags...

```
#1  f.Reason "Being naughty", f.Category_ID "1", c.Title "Low Level Disruption", c.Weight "1"
#1  Reason "Aggressively naughty!", Category "Aggressive Defiance", Category Weighting "4"
#1  Reason "Missed detention", Category "Missed Detention", Category Weighting "3"
```

They would have a total of `1+4+3` = `9` points to use in the `Worked Out Points Thing` equation.

The desired output therefore is essentially...

```
Student         LEAP Points     Flags Equation Points       LEAP Points minus Flag Points
D Wraight       1000            800                         200
D Wraight2      500             800                         -300
D Wraight3      1200            300                         900
```

---

From the SQL fiddle above, here is the required output.. I've missed out some students because I had to work these out manually:

```
STUDENT         FLAGS               LEAP            EQUATION
137608          4 (2+2)             12 (2+5+5)      8 (12-4)
139027          2 (2)               7 (2+5)         5 (7-2)
139041          4 (2+1+1+NULL)      8 (2+2+2+2)     4 (8-4)
139892          4 (4)               0               -4 (0-4)
138832          4 (4)               0               -4 (0-4)
34533           4 (4)               0               -4 (0-4)
137434          0                   10 (2*5)        10 (10-0)
```

---

Which will help us to work out the choices we make available to each student when looking at end of year reward trips.

Hope that makes sense.. it's kinda boggled my head trying to explain it..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I'd consider reducing the problem to its essential components, devoid of any extraneous info, and then provide an sqlfiddle with a representative data set and desired result set.

Comment: Also Flags looks like a comma-separated list. This is a bad idea.

Comment: I'll try my best. Could you explain what you mean with your second comment? I'm not sure what aspect of my DB you're referring to.

Comment: I *think* I've added an SQL fiddle... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figure out your 'formula' bit first because it's the deepest part. work outwards.
build a table of flags * weight per student

```
select sum(weight), student_id from flags f
join categories c
on f.category_id = c.id
group by student_id
```

so now you've got a table of flag values to minus from sum of transactions per student

```
select sum(points), recipient_id from transactions
group by recipient_id
```

so now we have two tables with positive and negative values by student id (assuming obviously that student id is recipient id)
you want those with transactions but without flags to appear in the result, so outer join.
and number minus null is null so ifnull function on the flags to get 0

```
select a.student, points - ifnull(penalties, 0) as netPoints
from

(select sum(points) as points, recipient_id as student from transactions
group by student) as a

left outer join

(select sum(weight) as penalties, student_id as student from flags f
join categories c
on f.category_id = c.id
group by student) as b

on

a.student = b.student
```

so with the name in there it's just

```
select
concat(firstname, ', ', surname) as name,
ifnull(points,0) as totalPoints,
ifnull(penalties,0) as totalPenalties,
ifnull(points,0) - ifnull(penalties, 0) as netPoints,
ifnull(countFlags, 0)

from
student
left join

(select sum(points) as points, recipient_id as student from transactions
group by student) as a

on student.id = a.student

left join

(select sum(weight) as penalties, count(f.id) as countFlags, student_id as student from flags f
join categories c
on f.category_id = c.id
group by student) as b

on

student.id = b.student
```

join condition is always from student's id column, which is never null.
there are probably more efficient ways, but who cares?

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for the detail. For a 50 point bounty, could you add in another column? I've tried it for myself but don't understand where to fit it in with the joins. I would like to include a `COUNT` of flags.. so I can see that Student X has been given 10 flags but because they're all quite serious his weighting is ~35 points. That make sense?

Comment: Well, that's easy - you wanna `count(f.id) as countFlags` of course! Included in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Returning to the question (and at the risk of repeating myself!), given the following data set, what would the desired result set look like...

```
SELECT * FROM flags;
+------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| ID   | Student_ID | Staff_ID | Datetime            | Period_ID | Category_ID | Action_Taken_Category_ID | Action_Taken_Status |
+------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| 8843 |     137608 |    35003 | 2014-03-11 08:31:00 |         8 |          16 |                        7 | P                   |
| 8844 |     137608 |    35003 | 2014-03-11 08:31:00 |         8 |          16 |                        7 | P                   |
| 8845 |     139027 |    35003 | 2014-03-11 08:31:00 |         8 |          16 |                        7 | P                   |
| 8846 |     139041 |    35003 | 2014-03-11 08:31:00 |         8 |          16 |                        7 | P                   |
| 8847 |     139041 |    34961 | 2014-03-11 09:01:02 |         2 |          12 |                       26 | P                   |
| 8848 |     139041 |    34996 | 2014-03-11 09:23:21 |         3 |          12 |                       27 | C                   |
| 8849 |     139041 |    35022 | 2014-03-11 11:07:46 |         4 |          34 |                       28 | P                   |      
| 8850 |     139892 |   138439 | 2014-03-11 11:12:47 |         4 |          21 |                        7 | C                   |
| 8851 |     138832 |   138439 | 2014-03-11 11:12:48 |         4 |          21 |                        7 | C                   |
| 8852 |      34533 |   138439 | 2014-03-11 11:12:48 |         4 |          21 |                        7 | C                   |
+------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------+---------------------+

SELECT * FROM categories;
+----+------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| ID | Type | Title                                | Weight | Added_By |
+----+------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| 10 | F    | Low level disruption                 |      1 |     NULL |
| 11 | F    | Swearing directly at another student |      2 |     NULL |
| 12 | F    | Late                                 |      1 |     NULL |
| 13 | F    | Absconded                            |      3 |     NULL |
| 14 | F    | Refusal to follow instruction        |      3 |     NULL |
| 15 | F    | Smoking                              |      2 |     NULL |
| 16 | F    | No homework                          |      2 |     NULL |
| 17 | F    | Disruptive outside classroom         |      2 |     NULL |
| 18 | F    | Eating/drinking in lesson            |      1 |     NULL |
| 19 | F    | Incorrect uniform/equipment          |      1 |     NULL |
| 20 | F    | Phone out in lesson                  |      3 |     NULL |
| 21 | F    | Aggressive defiance                  |      4 |     NULL |
| 22 | F    | Missed detention                     |      3 |     NULL |
| 23 | F    | Inappropriate behaviour/comments     |      3 |     NULL |
| 32 | F    | IT Misuse                            |   NULL |     NULL |
| 34 | F    | Inappropriate attitude towards staff |   NULL |     NULL |
| 35 | F    | Care & Guidance                      |   NULL |     NULL |
+----+------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------+

SELECT * FROM transactions;
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------+-------------+
| Transaction_ID | Datetime   | Giver_ID | Recipient_ID | Points | Category_ID |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------+-------------+
|             34 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       137608 |      2 |           1 |
|             35 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       139027 |      2 |           1 |
|             36 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       139041 |      2 |           1 |
|             37 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       139041 |      2 |           1 |
|             38 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       139041 |      2 |           1 |
|             39 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       139041 |      2 |           1 |
|             40 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       137434 |      2 |           1 |
|             41 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       137434 |      2 |           1 |
|             42 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       137434 |      2 |           1 |
|             43 | 2011-09-07 |    35019 |       137434 |      2 |           1 |
|             44 | 2011-09-07 |    35006 |       137434 |      2 |           1 |
|             45 | 2011-09-07 |    35006 |        90306 |      2 |           1 |
|             46 | 2011-09-07 |    35006 |        90306 |      2 |           1 |
|             47 | 2011-09-07 |    35006 |        90306 |      2 |           1 |
|             48 | 2011-09-07 |    35023 |       137608 |      5 |           2 |
|             49 | 2011-09-07 |    35023 |       139027 |      5 |           2 |
|             50 | 2011-09-07 |    35023 |       139564 |      5 |           2 |
|             51 | 2011-09-07 |    35023 |       139564 |      5 |           2 |
|             52 | 2011-09-07 |    35023 |       139564 |      5 |           2 |
|             53 | 2011-09-07 |    35023 |       137608 |      5 |           3 |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+--------+-------------+

SELECT id,UPN,Year_Group,Tutor_Group,SEN_Status,Flags FROM student;
+--------+---------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+
| id     | UPN           | Year_Group | Tutor_Group | SEN_Status | Flags  |
+--------+---------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+
| 137608 | A929238400044 |         11 | 11VID       | A          |        |
| 139027 | A929238401045 |         10 | 10KS        |            |        |
| 139041 | A929238402017 |         10 | 10RJ        | A          | FSM    |
| 139892 | A929238403018 |          9 | 9BW         |            |        |
| 139938 | A929238403020 |          9 | 9RH         |            |        |
| 137434 | A929238500027 |         11 | 11VID       |            |        |
| 138832 | A929238502002 |         10 | 10RY        | A          | FSM,PA |
| 34533  | A929238599028 |          0 |             |            | PA     |
| 139564 | A929241500025 |         12 |             |            | PA     |
| 90306  | A929253100006 |         12 | SLH         | A          | PA     |
+--------+---------------+------------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Ah OK, I see your point. It works for what I need it to though; not a heavily-used column.

Comment: Sorry Strawberry, I forgot about the output. I've worked it out manually and added it to my original question. I hope it's accurate but as it was done "by hand" there may be a discrepancy or two.